# pre-commit: How to disable the check for unstaged files?

Tags: git, pre-commit.com

My [pre-commit.com](//pre-commit.com) config looks like this:

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v3.2.0
    hooks:
    -   id: trailing-whitespace
    -   id: end-of-file-fixer
    -   id: check-yaml
    -   id: check-added-large-files
-   repo: https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8
    rev: ''  # pick a git hash / tag to point to
    hooks:
    -   id: flake8
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-isort
    rev: v5.7.0
    hooks:
    - id: isort
```

If I try to commit I get this error:

```
guettli@yoga15:~/projects/foo$ LANG=C git commit

[WARNING] Unstaged files detected.
[INFO] Stashing unstaged files to /home/guettli/.cache/pre-commit/patch1611141286.
Trim Trailing Whitespace.............................(no files to check)Skipped
Fix End of Files.....................................(no files to check)Skipped
Check Yaml...........................................(no files to check)Skipped
Check for added large files..........................(no files to check)Skipped
flake8...............................................(no files to check)Skipped
isort................................................(no files to check)Skipped
[INFO] Restored changes from /home/guettli/.cache/pre-commit/patch1611141286.

On branch feature/super-foo
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   .gitignore

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .pre-commit-config.yaml

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I would like to avoid the checking for unstaged files. I know what I do, and if I only want to commit some changes (not all), then I want to do this.

How to disable the check for unstaged files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your output, you didn't stage any files for commit.  so `git` itself prevented you from committing (not `pre-commit`) -- if you actually wanted to commit nothing you can use `git commit --allow-empty`.  If you want to stage some files for commit, use `git add`, or use `git commit -a`

Note that there were no errors from `pre-commit` here -- only a warning telling you that unstaged things were temporarily removed [so that partial commits can be linted successfully](https://pre-commit.com/#pre-commit-during-commits).

---

disclaimer: I'm the author of pre-commit

Comment: Thank you! I was blind. Maybe pre-commit could be more explicit here (for stupid and blind users like me).

Comment: I think pre-commit is much more than a simple helper. Why not use it for setting up python dev-environments which have requirements outside the pyhon world?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking specifically :S -- pre-commit works for all sorts of different programming languages (despite being written in python and being most popular in python)

Comment: @AnthonySottile Is there a way to disable `pre-commit` auto staging any unstaged changes? I'd like my Git messages to correctly reflect what changes took place> Its quite annoying.

Comment: @demberto `pre-commit` will never touch the staging area -- so you probably have some rogue thing running `git add`

Comment: @AnthonySottile idk then maybe its vs code itself but running `git` from command line with `--no-verify` doesn't cause that behaviour (i.e. pre-commit hooks don't get invoked)

Answer (score -1):

The pre-commit hook will use a way of iterating over the files in the changeset. There's probably something like `git ls-files` in there. If you use `git ls-files -c` then it will just show you the cached changes (the default) -- if you use `git ls-files -o` then it will show uncommitted (other) files as well.

If you're re-using someone else's hooks, then you'll need to investigate those hooks to determine if there's a way they can selectively disable the changes.

Comment: Your answer is about general pre-commit, but the question is about pre-commit.com hooks.

Comment: Sure, that's why I said you're going to have to look at the hooks that were provided by someone else. It's not a configuration option that exists or defaults and there aren't flags that are standardised. If you look at the code for the hooks, you now know what to look for.

Comment: You are right "look at the code" is almost always an answer (beside many other answers)